# BCrypt PasswordHasher:- FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, base64, asp.net-identity, bcrypt

*I went through almost all the related questions regarding this issue and could not found a similar situation or a reliable answer for my problem below.*

## Problem:

I am doing an ASP.NET Core MVC project. I employ Identity UI for user authentication and authorization. I have override the Idetity User default password hasher: `'PasswordHasher'` which is also implemented from `'IPasswordHasher'` interface *(ASP.NET Identity Version 2: PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations)*, and implemented my own class as follows:

**BCryptPasswordHasher.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace WATERrhythmWeb
{
    public class BCryptPasswordHasher<TUser> : PasswordHasher<TUser> where TUser : class
    {
        readonly BCryptPasswordSettings _settings;
        public BCryptPasswordHasher()
        {
        }
        public BCryptPasswordHasher(BCryptPasswordSettings settings)
        {
            _settings = settings;
        }

        public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(TUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
        {
            if (hashedPassword == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hashedPassword)); }
            if (providedPassword == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providedPassword)); }

            byte[] decodedHashedPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);

            // read the format marker from the hashed password
            if (decodedHashedPassword.Length == 0)
            {
                return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
            }

            // ASP.NET Core uses 0x00 and 0x01, so we start at the other end
            if (decodedHashedPassword[0] == 0xFF)
            {
                if (VerifyHashedPasswordBcrypt(decodedHashedPassword, providedPassword))
                {
                    // This is an old password hash format - the caller needs to rehash if we're not running in an older compat mode.
                    return _settings.RehashPasswords
                        ? PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded
                        : PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
                }
            }

            return base.VerifyHashedPassword(user, hashedPassword, providedPassword);
        }

        private static bool VerifyHashedPasswordBcrypt(byte[] hashedPassword, string password)
        {
            if (hashedPassword.Length < 2)
            {
                return false; // bad size
            }

            //convert back to string for BCrypt, ignoring first byte
            var storedHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashedPassword, 1, hashedPassword.Length - 1);

            return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, storedHash);
        }

        public override string HashPassword(TUser user, string password)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(password);
        }
    }
}
```

- The user **registration** occurs successfully and I get following
  hashed string for the password '`D4%%6gf45`'

  ```
  $2a$10$vUHdbnKLplTz4d4VgG.cHOx3O2jMAaeH5mFvNTVuf4wqoEtvRx442
  ```

- Nevertheless, when the same user tries to log in, I am getting the
  following error. (It is obvious this happen when the hashed password
  in the database is verified with the user input password):

  > `FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it`
  > `contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or`
  > `an illegal character among the padding characters.`

- The error is from the following line of code in
  `PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(TUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)` method of `PasswordHasher`
  class, where `hashedPassword` is being converted to a `base64 string`.

  ```
  byte[] decodedHashedPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);
  ```

Can somebody please explain to me how to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: not really sure what you're trying to do here, but if this `$2a$10$vUHdbnKLplTz4d4VgG.cHOx3O2jMAaeH5mFvNTVuf4wqoEtvRx442` is is what you're trying to decode `Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword)` then it has to fail. The hashedPassword is not a base64 string. Just look up base64 encoding and you'll see that `$` and `.` are not part of the base64 character set. Both characters serve as a sparator here.  I'm also not sure what *the hashed password in the database is converted to the original password* means. You can't restore the original from a hash.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Yes, now only I also realize that there is an error beyond the code here. As you said hashes cannot be decoded (one way). But I followed the article in this [link](https://andrewlock.net/migrating-passwords-in-asp-net-core-identity-with-a-custom-passwordhasher/) . I am also confused about the approach here.